# Should I Have Sign-up/Sign-in Flow To Implement In-App Purchase in tvOS App?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, tvos

I have 2 versions of my app, one for iOS and another for tvOS. In my app for iOS, I have sign-up and sign-in flow. Also, its in-app purchase capability is enabled. In my tvOS app it doesn't have those flows and its in-app purchase capability is not enabled, yet. So, the user should sign-up and sign-in in my app for iOS. If the user wants to use my app for tvOS, he needs to link his app for iOS to his app for tvOS through web socket.

Now, I wanna enable in-app purchase capability in my app for tvOS, but not for subscription purpose. Should I implement the sign-up/sign-in flow first before enabling it or it doesn't matter for in-app purchase in my case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-app purchases are to apple ID level, so if you purchase on an iOS device the purchase will associate with the Apple ID. Now in the tvOS app, you should add a button to [restore purchase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases) because if the user purchased something on iOS, on tvOS he has as well and vice versa. we have a case similar in our case we have to indicate our server that the user purchased, in this case, first we had to implement the sign-up/sign-in flow after, we implemented In-app purchases. (don’t forget purchase restoring flow)